# How to handle list index out of range?

Tags: python, list

In the below code, `t1` is a list containing 500000 strings. I'm splitting it and extracting the id which is available at the beginning of every string by matching by date.

```
tid=[]
for t in t1:
   dc=t.split("\t")
   if dc[7]=='2015-11-04':
       tid.append(dc[0])
len(tid)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-807d6fb08067> in <module>
      2 for t in t1:
      3     dc=t.split("\t")
----> 4     if dc[7]=='2015-11-04':
      5         tid.append(dc[0])
      6     del dc[:]

   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there any other way to do this or how can I solve this error?

Comment: Can u provide an example of `t1`?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Print out the offending values just before the point of error; how are you confused about those values?

Comment: @Sushil  "599958136804507649\tantallyon\t381421483\tfr\tTwitter for Android Tablets\tprofile_images/564397209450340352/SYbHdjhm_normal.jpeg\tSun\t2015-05-17\t55341\t1431876141\tRT DanielPilotte: HONTE À CHRISTIANE TAUBIRA la garde des sots Qui est de plus en plus contestée... "                                                 
this is one of string in t1

Comment: Is this in the form of a list or a string?

Comment: @Sushil yes it is in the form of string and this is one string

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if the list has at least n elements before accessing the nth element.

```
tid=[]
    for t in t1:
       dc=t.split("\t")
       
       if len(dc) > 7 and dc[7]=='2015-11-04':
           tid.append(dc[0])
    len(tid)
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that dc is less than 8 elements long.

This also means that tc does not have eight '\t' characters in the string.

Do `print(repr(t))` to see what t consists of.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `try` `except` code block to handle this.

For example:

```py
    tid=[]
    for t in t1:
       dc=t.split("\t")
       try:
           if dc[7]=='2015-11-04':
               tid.append(dc[0])
       except IndexError:
           pass
    len(tid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling the exception is the way to go:

```
tid=[]
for t in t1:
    dc=t.split("\t")
    try:
        if dc[7]=='2015-11-04':
            tid.append(dc[0])
    except IndexError:
        print("index error")
len(tid)
```